# rewriting a ActionScript function to php

Tags: php, function, actionscript

i am trying to write a ActionScript function with some math to php, its not coming out with the same results, could you give me a hand. This function calculates the distance between 2 coordinates for a hex map game.

The ActionScript funcion:

```
function tellDistance(p1:Point,p2:Point,debug:Boolean=false):Number{
    var dx:int=Math.abs(p1.x-p2.x);
    var dy:int=Math.abs(p1.y-p2.y);
    var auxY:int=dy;
    dy=Math.max(dy-Math.ceil(dx*.5),0);
   dy+=(auxY>=dx*.5 && dx%2==1 && ((p1.x%2==1 && p1.y>p2.y) || (p1.x%2==0 && p1.y<p2.y)))?1:0;
    return dx+dy;
}
```

My version in php (broken):

```
function tiles_distance($start_x, $start_y, $dest_x, $dest_y)
    {
    $x_dif = abs($start_x-$dest_x);
    $y_dif = abs($start_y-$dest_y);

    $y_dif_backup = intval($y_dif);

    $y_dif = max($y_dif-ceil($x_dif*0.5),0);
    $y_dif = $y_dif+($y_dif_backup>=$x_dif*.5 && $x_dif%2==1 && (($start_x%2==1 && $start_y>$dest_y) || ($start_x%2==0 && $start_y< $dest_y)))?1:0;

    return $x_dif+$y_dif;
    }
```

EDIT:

on ActionScript the coords would look like 20.80 and 32.81. on php i am giving the x and y coordinates separated. They would return an int value like 1 or 40.

Comment: Can you provide the return results of both?

Comment: That is not vanilla JavaScript. Perhaps ActionScript?

Comment: Agreed with Matt, Please confirm your code because Its not working from my fiddle...

Comment: personally, I am confused why the javascript would return 20.80 for an `int`

Answer (score 2):

It is probably because in your javascript you are immediately casting to `int` whereas in PHP you are not. The PHP code is probably giving you more accurate answers.

Also, I'm going to give you my favorite quote:

> "Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place.
>   Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by
>   definition, not smart enough to debug it."
>   - Brian Kernighan

Cut out that ternary `if` statement crap so you can see what's going on.

Comment: +1 mostly for the ternary hate. One of my coworkers, otherwise an awesome guy whose code is always great and easy to follow, loves throwing in ternary operators. /pet peeve

Comment: ternary operators are awesome - they just suck if the check's get too long. I defy you to find an easier way to, say, clamp a value: `value = ( value < 0.0 ) ? 0.0 : ( value > 1.0 ) ? 1.0 : value;`

Comment: @divillysausages - that's pretty neat, but still nearly impossible to interpret without knowing ahead of time what it does. When you spend a lot of time debugging somebody else's code, you begin to appreciate simplicity/readability ahead of code size efficiency.